# What is the most efficient circle collision algorithm for my case?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, collision-detection, game-physics, physics-engine

Hello :) I am trying to make similar simulation to a game like agar.io - where there are many circles within square world. The circles vary a lot in size - some have radius 1, some have radius even 150.

Just checking every circle-circle collision is too expensive - it is O(n^2) on every physics tick.

Hope you could help me <3 Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it a 2D world? You are checking for circle collisions of non-filled circles with an infinitesimal small line-width? I believe that middle of division problematic can be avoided.

Comment: Yes it is 2D world. The circles are filled - but it doesn't matter as collisions are usually detected when they even touch.

Comment: As this is a simulation, do you repeat collision checks? How much does the configuration change from one check to the next? Can the first check take longer, e.g. to build up data structures?

Comment: Yes I do repeat it every physics tick. Also I am using substepping for the improved result. The circles can move however they don't teleport from one place to another. Smaller circles move faster, bigger circles move slower. First checks don't necessarily take longer - although if I use some complex data structure for this problem like quad tree or KD tree then of course it might be the case

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It is as small task as it can get. I ask about the basic algorithm for the issue - regardless if it is Quad Tree or grid approach - the implementation is not an issue. I can't start working on the issue if I don't know which algorithm I should follow - because entire data structures, classes and other stuff depends on which algorythm i will use. If   this place isn't good for this question then which place is?

Comment: You could make this question a better fit for SO by including your existing O(n^2) algorithm and asking how it might be improved or optimised.  You also state that it is "too expensive" without qualification.  What is the current performance and what performance do you need to achieve for it to no longer be "too expensive"?  In real terms rather than general "complexity" terms, since it is entirely possible that useful improvement could be made while still being O(n^2). That describes the number of iterations, not the compute intensity of each iteration.

Comment: Also, I would keep the first two paragraphs and delete the rest which is a description of solutions you have already discounted or failed to make work.  That is rather constraining or leading the kind of answer you will get.  Better to leave it open and get a wider range of ideas.  Even if some of them may duplicate your ideas.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your advice. I will keep it in mind for my next questions

Comment: Any similar algorithms for rectangles/squares should work, too, as the circles have `pi/4` of their area.

Comment: Ok.  If it is good advice, why not edit _this_ question?  That is how SO works; improve the question in response to comments -avoid discussion and clarification in comments - fix the question.

Comment: Ok I removed the parts of algorythms i tried. There is no boundary of "Now it is ok performace". I want to use as many circles as possible before it gets laggy. Simple as this - so I just use best solution possible and accept whatever performance I will get

Comment: The best solution I know is to ditch time-stepping and use event scheduling for reasons described [here](https://www.informs-sim.org/wsc10papers/135.pdf). Quick summary: 1) events involving collisions happen when they happen, not every delta-t; and 2) when event times are rounded to the nearest delta-t it introduces errors, sometimes huge ones. Event scheduling enables the techniques described in [this paper](https://www.informs-sim.org/wsc05papers/118.pdf).  You get greater computational efficiency as discussed in the second paper, and better accuracy for reasons discussed in the first.

Comment: The general solution is to use a [quad tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) which breaks the world into smaller sections, then you only need to compare circles against circles in each section. Building a quad tree is O(n) and in best case can reduce collision complexity to O(n) worst case is still O(n^2)